# RecyclerView ItemDecoration onDraw

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The spec for [RecyclerView.ItemDecoration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html) says that `onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent)`  is deprecated.  Instead, they say to override `onDraw(Canvas, RecyclerView, RecyclerView.State)`.

However, I don't understand what kind of State object I should pass to this method.  I see State passed internally in RecyclerView's methods like: **onLayoutChildren**, **scrollVerticallyBy**, and **onFocusSearchFailed**.  But I see no examples to use the State object programmatically to pass to **onDraw** method.  Does anybody have any input into this?

Answer (score 3):

`OnDraw()` will be called by `RecyclerView` with proper state set, you need not call it yourself. Also, its recommended to override `onDrawOver()` of `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` instead.

An example of a decoration that draws divider lines between RecyclerView items: https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e

Comment: Thanks, but your link does not use onDrawOver() as an example.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky yep. its a bit old ;)